# Anormal layout settings at iOS Simulator run time

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, position, ios-simulator

Well, my problem it´s not code related. Almost all visual iOS Applications that i make at xCode got distortions at run time, for example I put a text input at the very center of the Mainboard and the simulator puts it way below than that at execution time. I would attached an image of an example regarding the problem, but I don´t have the reputation. What could the problem be? I´ve already uncheked NSLayout settings

Comment: Maybe you are constructing your views for 4 inch screen and run Simulator for 3,5 inch screen? or vice versa. How much is the difference between real and expected positions?

Comment: Could you host a screenshot somewhere and paste the URL so I can see what's happening? Would be great to see an IB screen and a sim screen.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/mv8d1kszn/ Run time http://postimg.org/image/miobnw3b7/ Storyboard    I believe it´s the 4 and 3.5 screen issue. How could I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controls Below Normal at Execution Time xCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285555/controls-below-normal-at-execution-time-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your views for 4 inch screen and then run Simulator for 3,5 inch screen. No surprise that your positions are different. You should use Autolayout + constraints or `UIView:autoresizingMask` property to make your GUI change automaticaly for different screens.

Start with this article http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1